how to test a website (with multiple services) on localhost on my laptop with my phone
While I can connect to the local IP address of my macbook (say, 192.168.1.101) from my iPhone (http://192.168.1.101:8080/index.html) to test my website, the web app itself is, in turn, requesting two other local services at http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost:3010. All these localhost addresses get replaced with the real addresses of the services when pushed to the outside server. But, how do I test my website within this local world? While I can get to http://192.168.1.101:8080/index.html from my iPhone, the iPhone has no clue where is http://localhost:3000. Of course, I could replace all instances of localhost with 192.168.1.101 but tomorrow that dynamically assigned IP address could change, so this does not seem like a very reliable approach. Is there a more elegant solution?
More details below
My web app is 100% client-side. In fact, it is served off Github Pages, so there is no way to manipulate anything once the repo is git pushed to Github. The app itself queries two other services (running elsewhere in production, but all of them running on my MacBook in development). My development process is

make all the changes and test
npx gulp so the various files are cleaned, minified, and concatenated
do the git dance (add, commit, push)

I have a snippet of JS code which is like so
const globals = {

    uri: {
        api: window.location.hostname === 'localhost'
            ? `http://localhost:3010/v3` 
            : 'https://real/server1/',

        map:  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' 
            ? `http://localhost:3000` 
            : 'https://real/server2/'
    },
    …
}

and further down
await res = fetch(`${globals.uri.api}`?queryParams);
…
L.TileLayer(`${globals.uri.map}/z/x/y`);

I test the app itself by firing up both api and map services, and then starting my web app with npx http-server and going to http://localhost:8080/index.html. This system has worked very well till now.
Now I want to test my website on a real phone instead of the browser webdev tools responsive mode. I tried both localtunnel and ngrok and failed spectacularly with both of them because they insert a page that one has to agree to and click on a button… so, while I can do that for my web app, my web app gets stuck when trying to reach the other two services.
Now what?

"All these localhost addresses get replaced with the real addresses of the services when pushed to the outside server." - What process does this?  Can that same process replace those addresses with 192.168.0.101 at build/run time?  After all, the more the functionality matches the target deployed functionality, the better.  At worst, when the local IP is different I wouldn't expect to have to do anything more than update a single configuration value to match it.  Which is inconvenient, but not terrible and a fair price to pay for a frequently changing address.

"Which is inconvenient, but not terrible and a fair price to pay for a frequently changing address" -- sigh, I was afraid of that :)

perhaps I spoke too soon… I am having the darndest time trying to connect to my MacBook from my iPhone on Mac OS X Sonoma

@punkish Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description what these other "local services" on port 3000 and 3010 are. How do you access/request these services and from where? Why is the hostname localhost somehow hard coded in your application and not dynamically generated from the (server) code?

"they insert a page that one has to agree to and click on a button" - I've used ngrok some weeks ago, and at that point, it did not do such a thing. Anyways, ngrok is a great solution for what you want to achieve

You should try mDNS.
Since you are using a mac, find the name of your Mac using hostname command (at the Terminal prompt).
Use that name with .local extension in your URL. E.g. http://Punkishs-MacBook.local:3000/
Btw ngrok should work fine with a paid plan. Same with https://pinggy.io/ which is a neat alternative.
